# powershell v2 remoting - How do you enable unecrypted traffic

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I'm writing a powershell v2 script that I'd like to run against a remote server.  When I run it, I get the error :

> Connecting to remote server failed
>   with the following error message : The
>   WinRM client cannot process the
>   request. Unencrypted traffic is
>   currently disabled in the client
>   configuration. Change the client
>   configurati on and try the request
>   again. For more information, see the
>   about_ Remote_Troubleshooting Help
>   topic.

I looked at the online help for about _ Remote_Troubleshooting, but it didn't point me towards how to enable unecrypted traffic.  Below is the script that I'm using that is causing me problems.

Note: I have already run Enable-PSRemoting on the remote machine to allow it to accept incoming requests.
I have tried to use a session option variable, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

```
$key = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds"
Set-ItemProperty $key ConsolePrompting True

$tvar = "password"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -string $tvar -asPlainText –force
$username="domain\username"
$mySessionOption = New-PSSessionOption -NoEncryption 
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)

invoke-command -filepath C:\scripts\RemoteScript.ps1  -sessionoption $mySessionOption -authentication digest -credential $credential -computername RemoteServer
```

How do I enable unencrypted traffic?

Answer (score 1):

New-PSSessionOption has a -NoEncryption option.

```
$PSSessionOption = New-PSSessionOption -NoEncryption
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I added a sessionOption to my call and still get the same error. I've edited my question to include this command.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I see you asked your question here also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469791/powershell-v2-remoting-how-do-you-enable-unecrypted-traffic Does the answer there help?

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, you need to configure WinRM (the underlying service that mediates remote invocation) to use unencrrypted HTTP transport. Look up "winrm quickconfig".